# Google Calendar API requesting events list JavaScript

Tags: javascript, request, google-calendar-api, response, access-token

I have a project in which the user submits a form and a google calendar event is created based on the parameters that the user provides. I want to use the start time and end time that is given to me by the user to check their primary google calendar to see if there is already an event which is taking place in that time frame, and log it in the console. This is my code with the client id and API key censored:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Google Calendar Event Scheduling</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>Google Calendar Event Scheduling</p>

  <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
  <button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
  <br>
  <button hidden id="event_button" onclick="handleEventClick()">Create Default Event</button>
  <button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>
  <br>


  <br>
  <br>


  <form name="event_form" id="event_form">
    <label for="event_summary">Event Summary:</label>
    <br>
    <input name='event_summary' id="event_summary" type="text">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="event_location">Event Location:</label>
    <br>
    <input name="event_location" id="event_location" type="text">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="event_description">Event Description:</label>
    <br>
    <textarea name="event_description" id="event_description" type="text"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="start_time">Start Time:</label>
    <br>
    <input name="start_time" id="start_time" type="datetime-local">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="end_time">End Time:</label>
    <br>
    <input name="end_time" id="end_time" type="datetime-local">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>


  <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* exported gapiLoaded */
    /* exported gisLoaded */
    /* exported handleAuthClick */
    /* exported handleSignoutClick */

    // TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
    const CLIENT_ID = client_id
    const API_KEY = null; // 

    // Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
    const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest';

    // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
    // included, separated by spaces.
    const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

    let tokenClient;
    let gapiInited = false;
    let gisInited = false;

    document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('event_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

    /**
     * Callback after api.js is loaded.
     */
    function gapiLoaded() {
      gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
    }

    /**
     * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
     * discovery doc to initialize the API.
     */
    async function initializeGapiClient() {
      await gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
      });
      gapiInited = true;
      maybeEnableButtons();

    }

    /**
     * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
     */
    function gisLoaded() {
      tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        callback: '', // defined later
      });
      gisInited = true;
      maybeEnableButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
     */
    function maybeEnableButtons() {
      if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
        document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('event_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
      }
    }

    async function isFreeDuringEvent(startTime, endTime) {
  console.log(startTime);
  console.log(endTime);


  const calendarId = 'primary';
  let response;
  try {
    const request = {
          'calendarId': 'primary',
          'timeMin': startTime,
          'timeMax': endTime,
          'singleEvents': true,
          'maxResults': 10,
          'orderBy': 'startTime',
        };
    console.log(request);
    response = await gapi.client.calendar.events.list(request);
    console.log(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err.message);
  }
  
    console.log(response);
    const events = response.result.items;
    let hasEventDuringTimeRange = false;

    if (events.length) {
      for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        const event = events[i];
        const eventStartTime = new Date(event.start.dateTime);
        const eventEndTime = new Date(event.end.dateTime);

        if (eventStartTime < new Date(endTime) && eventEndTime > new Date(startTime)) {
          hasEventDuringTimeRange = true;
          console.log(`User has an event during the specified time: ${event.summary}`);
        }
      }
    }

    if (!hasEventDuringTimeRange) {
      console.log('User does not have any events during the specified time.');
    }
    
  
}



    /**
     *  Sign in the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleAuthClick() {
      tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
        if (resp.error !== undefined) {
          throw (resp);
        }
        document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
        // document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
        document.getElementById('authorize_button').hidden = true;
        await listUpcomingEvents();
        // await createEvent(); // Call createEvent function after initialization
      };

      if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
        // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
        // when establishing a new session.
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: 'consent' });
      } else {
        // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: '' });
      }
    }

    // get form element
    const formElement = document.querySelector('form#event_form')

    // convert the form to JSON
    const getFormJSON = (form) => {
      const data = new FormData(form);
      return Array.from(data.keys()).reduce((result, key) => {
        result[key] = data.get(key);
        return result;
      }, {});
    };
    let submittedEventObj;

    // handle the form submission event, prevent default form behaviour, check validity, convert form to JSON
    const handler = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const valid = formElement.reportValidity();
      if (valid) {
        const result = getFormJSON(formElement);
        result.start_time = result.start_time + ':00'
        result.end_time = result.end_time + ':00'
        console.log(result)
        // submittedEventObj = {
        //   'summary': result.event_summary,
        //   'location': result.event_location,
        //   'description': result.event_description,
        //   'start': {
        //     'dateTime': result.start_time,
        //     'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
        //   },
        //   'end': {
        //     'dateTime': result.end_time,
        //     'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
        //   }

        // };
        submittedEventObj = {
          'summary': result.event_summary,
          'location': result.event_location,
          'description': result.event_description,
          'start': {
            'dateTime': result.start_time,
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
          },
          'end': {
            'dateTime': result.end_time,
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
          }

        };
        console.log(submittedEventObj);


        isFreeDuringEvent(result.start_time, result.end_time);


        tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
          if (resp.error !== undefined) {
            throw (resp);
          }
          
          await createEvent(submittedEventObj); // Call createEvent function after initialization\
        };

        if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
          // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
          // when establishing a new session.
          tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: 'consent' });
        } else {
          // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
          tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: '' });
        }
      }
    }

    formElement.addEventListener("submit", handler)







    function handleEventClick() {
      tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
      
      const event = {
      'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
      'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
      'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
      'start': {
        'dateTime': '2023-06-30T09:00:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
      },
      'end': {
        'dateTime': '2023-06-30T17:00:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
      }
    };

        if (resp.error !== undefined) {
          throw (resp);
        }
        await createEvent(event); // Call createEvent function after initialization\
      };

      if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
        // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
        // when establishing a new session.
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: 'consent' });
      } else {
        // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: '' });
      }

    }



    




    async function createEvent(submittedEvent) {
      console.log('Event created: %s', submittedEvent.summary);

      await gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
        calendarId: 'primary',
        resource: submittedEvent,
      }, function (err, submittedEvent) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err);
          return;
        }

      });
    }





    /**
     *  Sign out the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleSignoutClick() {
      const token = gapi.client.getToken();
      if (token !== null) {
        google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
        gapi.client.setToken('');
        document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
        document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
        document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    }

    /**
     * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
     * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
     * appropriate message is printed.
     */
    async function listUpcomingEvents() {
      let response;
      try {
        const request = {
          'calendarId': 'primary',
          'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
          'showDeleted': false,
          'singleEvents': true,
          'maxResults': 10,
          'orderBy': 'startTime',
        };
        response = await gapi.client.calendar.events.list(request);
      } catch (err) {
        document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
        return;
      }

      const events = response.result.items;
      if (!events || events.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'No events found.';
        return;
      }
      // Flatten to string to display
      const output = events.reduce(
        (str, event) => `${str}${event.summary} (${event.start.dateTime || event.start.date})\n`,
        'Events:\n');
      document.getElementById('content').innerText = output;
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
  <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

After attempting to solve this, I determined that the problem is most likely the reponse and request in my `isFreeDuringEvent` function. I was wondering if there was something I am missing or if there is a problem in my code. Thank You.

Comment: is there an error?

Comment: Yes: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'result')
    at isFreeDuringEvent ((index):149:29)
isFreeDuringEvent @ (index):149
await in isFreeDuringEvent (async)
handler @ (index):252`